# Ubuntu 12.04 php PEAR package problem

Tags: 12.04, permissions, apache2, php

I am using LAMP server on my Ubuntu 12.04 system. Before this time I have installed prestashop without any issues. But after a long time when I tried to install prestashop today, it really showed me a strange error. The error is like this:

```
Warning: require(/var/www/Prestashop/config/config.inc.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/Prestashop/index.php on line 27 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/Prestashop/config/config.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear/PEAR') in /var/www/Prestashop/index.php on line 27
```

For that I decided to debug the error so I went through many blogs and forums and I checked my php.ini file. The file is like [this](http://pastebin.com/9SZ0r19k).

After going through many blogs someone had said that the error is for php pear package the link is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1025510).

After that I just made edit my php.ini pear url like this:

```
;UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/PEAR"
```

After that I just restarted my apache server but it did not worked for me. The same error is coming. So here can someone kindly tell me what's the issue here? and how to solve this?

Comment: I have made paste the total file of `config.inc.php` in this link
http://pastebin.com/0wqDgAh3

Comment: strange..When I tried `ls /var/www/Prestashop/config/config.inc.php` in terminal  it is showing `ls: cannot access /var/www/Prestashop/config/config.inc.php: No such file or directory` but I have checked the file is exist there

Comment: Good. :) Please post output of: `ls /var/www/Prestashop/config/`

Comment: Again the strange error .. 
`ls /var/www/Prestashop/config.php` it showed me `ls: cannot access /var/www/Prestashop/config.php: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try `ls /var/www/Prestashop/config/` and the not the one you tried above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10252/discussion-between-saji89-and-newuser)

Answer (score 2):

The error is produced by [`require()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) function. This function it will halt the php script when:

- the given file (in your case `/var/www/Prestashop/config/config.inc.php` file) doesn't exist or
- when the user that call the function doesn't have permission to read that file.

According with:

```
Warning: require(/var/www/Prestashop/config/config.inc.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/Prestashop/index.php on line 27
```

your issue falls into the second case. To prevent this, you have to change the permissions for `/var/www/Prestashop/config/config.inc.php` file so that to allow other users to read the file. You can do this by running the following command from terminal:

```
chmod +r /var/www/Prestashop/config/config.inc.php
```

If the error will appear after for other files too, follow the same method to change the permissions.

Check also the permissions for `config` directory. These must to be something like: `drwxr-xr-x`. If not, use this command in terminal:

```
chmod +rx /var/www/Prestashop/config
```

Comment: I don't think thats a good solution because by changing the file permission config or congig.inc.php is not solving the issue. I had gone through many forums and someone of them had told to change the  folder and files permission. But that's a very ugly method. Applications do have some access for their files and folders and they have done that for the security. And by the way I had done simple installation before this time and at that time I did not changed any permission for files or folders.

Comment: @newuser Well, if you don't change permission for others to read that file, how do you suppose to read the file? There is no other solutions in unix like systems... Is not an ugly method, it's the usual method.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions on directory `/var/www/Prestashop/config` are [wrong](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6012892/). They are `drwx------` meaning that ONLY the `newuser` user can access them. The webserver is run as `www-data` and obviously it can't access your config directory.

There's absolutely no harm at adding read permissions to both group and all.

```
chmod +rx /var/www/Prestashop/config
```

It might be considered a security issue adding write permission to the directory, but also this is disputable since `/tmp/` is always accessible and malicious software tends to use that as a support directory.

Of course don't give write access to the files themselves as **that** would be a security issue.

If you really don't want to make it readable to the world you can change the owner to `www-data`

```
sudo chown www-data /var/www/Prestashop/config
```

that should be enough since files inside the directory are world readable (except for the `xml` folder that again needs the right ownership or permissions).